# FATAL EXCEPTION : main (Android std)

Tags: java, android

While I run this on my device it will crash and my logcat is as below:

```
2020-12-19 17:03:28.204 24798-24798/com.example.emergencynotificationhealthcare E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.emergencynotificationhealthcare, PID: 24798
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity       
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2799)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1573)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6605)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:999)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:889)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
 android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.emergencynotificationhealthcare.Login.onCreate(Login.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6964)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2752)
```

Here is my activity_register.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:transitionName="logo_logo"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_new"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:transitionName="logo_text"
    android:textColor="#ff8e88"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register to start"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="15"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:transitionName="user_tran"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Email"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/phoneNo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:transitionName="password_tran"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="User Type"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="17dp"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="User" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Guardian"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#ff8e88"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:transitionName="button_tran"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/register_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Already have an account? LOGIN"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:transitionName="login_register_tran"/>
```

Here is my Login.java:

```
Button callRegister, login_btn;
ImageView image;
TextView logoText, sloganText;
TextInputLayout username,password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    callRegister = findViewById(R.id.register_screen);
    image = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    logoText = findViewById(R.id.logo_name);
    sloganText = findViewById(R.id.slogan_name);
    username = findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    login_btn = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);

    callRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Register.class);

            Pair[] pairs = new Pair[7];

            pairs[0] = new Pair<View,String>(image,"logo_logo");
            pairs[1] = new Pair<View,String>(logoText,"logo_text");
            pairs[2] = new Pair<View,String>(sloganText,"logo_desc");
            pairs[3] = new Pair<View,String>(username,"user_tran");
            pairs[4] = new Pair<View,String>(password,"password_tran");
            pairs[5] = new Pair<View,String>(login_btn,"button_tran");
            pairs[6] = new Pair<View,String>(callRegister,"login_register_tran");

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Login.this,pairs);
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Here is my activity_login.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_new"
    android:transitionName="logo_logo"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logo_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
    android:text="Hi, Welcome Back!"
    android:transitionName="logo_text"
    android:textColor="#ff8e88"
    android:textSize="40sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/slogan_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign in to continue"
    android:transitionName="logo_desc"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/username"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <CheckBox
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Remember Me" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:text="Forget Password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#ff8e88"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/antic"
        android:text="New Member? REGISTER"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you inflate the correct layout file? `activity_register` is the name of the file you said, but your code uses
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);`.

Try replacing that with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);` if that's not the case.

Comment: I refer to this tutorial video on YouTube the link is as follow: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5jb9EteFAOD_Tz2dPlsw-1ViOmM57txh
I am not sure what is wrong with my codes...

Comment: Your code uses `callRegister = findViewById(R.id.register_screen);` in `Login.java`. However, in your XML file for login you don't have a view with the id `register_screen.` Your `callRegister` variable will therefore be null. You need to add an ID to the button with the text 'New Member? REGISTER'.

Comment: It shows no error in my logcat but when I click on text 'New Member? REGISTER', it did not display the register page, it goes back to the splash screen instead on my device.